# Problem with opening new window in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('input[name=sumb_but]').bind('click', function(){
        var print_text = "Test page";
        var newWin = window.open('','printWindow','Toolbar=0,Location=0,Directories=0,Status=0,Menubar=0,Scrollbars=0,Resizable=0'); 
        newWin.document.write(print_text);
        return false;
    });
})
```

**Problem**

IE shoots error message ***Object required*** in line

```
newWin.document.write(print_text);
```

Comment: try making print_text a global variable, just guessing.

Comment: make newWin as global variable, and also try setting innerHTML of newWin.document.body as print_text , `newWin.document.body.innerHTML = print_text;`

Comment: nope. Just the same error.
You can check - http://wayo.ru/test/

Comment: which IE version are you using. That link is working for me (IE8)

Comment: Your example works in IE7 and IE8 just like it does in Firefox 6. Perhaps your **Object required** error is thrown somewhere else.